# Convert this LINQ code back to a Loop (or Why is this object sometimes null)

Tags: javascript, linq, knockout.js

I have an Upload Button in an app that uploads a deliveries object, but sometimes the deliveries object is null when it gets to the web service.

Full code is below, but it is this bit that I am having trouble unpicking. I believe this is LINQ code, so can anyone help me convert this back into a loop so that I can begin to try and understand why the `deliveries` object might be null?

```
var deliveries = Enumerable.From(results).Select(function (r) {
    r.transactionDate = r.transactionDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
    return r;
}).ToArray();
```

Full code:

```
me.uploadClicked = function () {
playClicked();
coreViewModel.busyMessage("Processing delivery data...");

deliveryRepository.GetTodaysDeliveries(function (results) {
    var deliveries = Enumerable.From(results).Select(function (r) {
        r.transactionDate = r.transactionDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        return r;
    }).ToArray();


    window.setTimeout(function () {
        coreViewModel.busyMessage("Uploading delivery data...");

        var objUploadDeliveries = Object.create({
            objStore: Object.create({
                storeTypeID: coreViewModel.store.storeTypeID(),
                storeID: coreViewModel.store.id()
            }),
            objDeliveries: deliveries
        });

        var comm = new URLHelper();
        var xhr = $.ajax({
            url: comm.hosturl() + "UploadDelivery",
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function(xh) { xh.setRequestHeader("token", coreViewModel.token); },
            data: objUploadDeliveries,
            dataType: 'json',

            success: function (result) {
                if (!result) {
                    playError();
                    return;
                }
                playUploadComplete();
            },
            error: function (x, e) {
                playError();
                errorHandler(x, e);
                },
            timeout: 60000
        });
    }, 20000);
});
}
```

The GetTodaysDeliveries function is as follows:

```
GetTodaysDeliveries: function (callback) {
    deliverysDatabase.GetDeliveries(function (results) {
        $.each(results, function (index, result) {
            result.transactionDate = moment(result.transactionDate).utc();
        });

        var todaysResults = Enumerable.From(results).Where(function (r) {
            return moment().isSame(r.transactionDate, 'day');
        }).ToArray();

        return callback(todaysResults);
    });
}
```

and the deliverydatabase.GetDeliveries function inside that is as follows:

```
GetDeliveries: function (callback) {
    var me = this;

    db.transaction(
        function (context) {
            context.executeSql("SELECT barcode, titleName, delivered, expected, isNews, supplier, supplierId, transactionDate FROM delivery ORDER BY titlename", [], function (context, result) {
                if (result.rows.length > 0) {
                    var results = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                        results.push(result.rows.item(i));
                    }

                    return callback(results);
                } else {
                    return callback([]);
                }
            }, me.ErrorHandler);
        }
        , me.ErrorHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code snippet takes the array from results, formats the date, and then returns an array. So deliverables is the same as results but with date formatted. If delivarables is null, then results must be empty or null. You can check this by inserting a

```
console.log("test");
```

into the loop

This is the unlinqd code snippet

```
var deliveries = [];
results.forEach(function(item)
{
  var item.transactionDate = item.transactionDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
  deliveries.push(item);
};
```

I hope this clears it up.

Comment: I need to therefore look further back and work out why `results` is coming back empty. That unLINQed code really helped, thank you.